# I'd like to add numbers to values in batch like adding 1+1

Tags: batch-file

so I'm making a game and i wanted to give a concussion to my character by telling the game how many times your character has his their head
`set concussion= 1`
then add numbers or something
any little helps

Comment: You need to show us what you tried so far :)

Comment: Are you asking how to do math in batch? https://ss64.com/nt/ Read the whole thng.

Comment: @RC. - According to the tag, yes.

Comment: Na. I'd say in batch, some of the notation is so obfuscated that demonstrated attempts are not remotely helpful.

Comment: @SomethingDark thanks

Comment: @Bathsheba - the notation is obvious once you're familiar with the language

Comment: After all these years I still find batch progamming a dark art. I don't think I truly understand what's going on.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Bathsheba, since the question has only a single batch-file tag, and since you admit that you don't understand batch programming, _(finding it an obfuscated dark art)_, why are you reading and commenting on it's questions? It wouldn't show the site in a good light if we all posted negatively about subjects which didn't match our favoured languages.

Comment: i know how to make a text adventure this was just a simple question i had
if you want to check out my game you can
[link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B42T-n1B2OGZdnNCemV0Y3hJQ0k?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Your first job is to write<sup>1</sup>

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

at the top of the batch file.

Then something of the form

```
Set count=1
```

followed by

```
Set /a count = !count! + 1
```

will increment `count` by 1.

---

<sup>1</sup>Acknowledge @SomethingDark, apparently this step is not necessary although it might get you out of trouble as your batch file grows.

Comment: Delayed expansion is not necessarily required for this (although it most likely doesn't hurt).

Comment: thank you bathsheba

Comment: Adding to what @SomethingDark said, delayed expansion is only necesary in specific cases, such as inside loops. In most cases you would use `%` instead of `!` around you variables. Read [this](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for more information about when to use delayed expansion.